# Objective C method not working properly inside objective C++

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm calling a objective C method in objective C++ class where I create a label also hiding the status bar but the status bar is hiding fine while the label was not getting created and shown! If I call that method anywhere else other than this objective C++ class it works fine without any issue

The Objective C++ class is below

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue )

{
   // ensure that this callback was invoked for a route change
   if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

   {
       // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not
       //      because of a category change.
       CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;

       CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason) );
       SInt32 routeChangeReason;
       CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

       if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {
            //Handle Headset Unplugged
           NSLog(@"PluggedOut");


       }
       else if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable)
       {
           //Handle Headset plugged in
           NSLog(@"Something Plugged In");

           audiotest *test = [[audiotest alloc] init];
           ArmorController *armorcontroller =[[ArmorController alloc]init];


       NSLog(@"%d", [test Checkheadphonestatus]);
            if([test Checkheadphonestatus] == 1)
            {
         [armorcontroller deviceconnectedalert];
            }
            else if([test Checkheadphonestatus] == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Device not connected");
            }


       }


   }
```

The objective C method which not executing  properly inside objective C++ class is below

```
- (void) deviceconnectedalert
{

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];


     self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 320, 30)];
    [self.titleLabel setText:@"Device Connected Successfully!"];
    self.titleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.titleLabel];

}
```

Comment: Your file extension is .mm, right?

Comment: Just make sure that "deviceconnectedalert" is running on main thread.

Comment: Yes @HAS its .mm only

Comment: @Hamdullahshah how to do that?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do work here
});